# Page number request doesn't change R

Tags: html, r, loops, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the following web page:

http://www.tiendasjumbo.co/televisores-y-sonido/televisores/?PS=24&O=OrderByPriceDESC#1

as you can see it has the page number 1 (#1), I want to scrape page number 1, 2 and 3, with the following code in R:

```
ptv <- matrix(, nrow = 5, ncol = 1)
tv <- matrix(, nrow = 5, ncol = 1)
for( j in 1:5){
doc <- read_html(paste0("http://www.tiendasjumbo.co/televisores-y-sonido/televisores/?PS=24&O=OrderByPriceDESC#',j,'"))
ptv[j,1] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//span[@class='bestPrice']"))
tv[j,1] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//div[@class='item-title']"))
}
```

Even if I change the page number manually in the code (without the loop), I always have information from page number 1. How can I do to get the information for page number 2 and 3? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a typo where you create `doc`. It should be `doc <- read_html(paste0("http://www.tiendasjumbo.co/televisores-y-sonido/televisores/?PS=24&O=OrderByPriceDESC#",j))`.

Comment: I think the address is not correct. Try with `doc <- read_html(paste0("http://www.tiendasjumbo.co/televisores-y-sonido/televisores/?P%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BS=24&O=OrderByPriceDESC#",j))`

Comment: No, I just have the result from page number 1

Comment: Then it is not a problem on how the site is made.